# How to manage idle channels in rabbitmq using node.js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I want to delete idle channels automatically. I have currently working multiplier game in ios / android and flash. please guide me how i can manage the idle channels.

Due to many channels ..i want to restart the rabbitmq server within 3-4 days. Is there any other solutions for managing idle channel in rabbitmq.[image]

Comment: What about using `hearbeat` option?